# What is the difference in calling a method explicitely and implicitely?

Tags: ruby

As per my understanding,  in ruby we cannot call private method on self (calling private methods on self explicitly is not possible).  If you call a method without any receiver, then it gets called on self, Then why cant we call a private method with self itself?

Sorry but I didn't really get what exactly is the difference in calling explicitly and implicitly(with self and without self).

I know that I may get down votes but still want to know. Can anyone tell me please.

Comment: I suppose the implementation is easier if you don't have to take `self` into account. Something like: if the method is private and there is a receiver then raise a `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in MRI, these concepts are identical. An explicit call *is* a public call, an implicit call *is* a private call.

The parser recognizes three kinds of method calls:

1. methods with an explicit receiver e.g. `obj.foo(1)`
2. methods with an implicit receiver e.g. `foo(1)`
3. methods with an implicit receiver and no arguments e.g. `foo`

The evaluator recognizes each of these as a different "call type". These types are (respectively):

1. `CALL_PUBLIC`
2. `CALL_FCALL`
3. `CALL_VCALL`

This call type is checked before making the call:

```
if (((noex & NOEX_MASK) & NOEX_PRIVATE) && scope == CALL_PUBLIC) {
    return NOEX_PRIVATE;
}
```

I.e. if the method is private and the call type is public, don't call the method (protected calls work the same way but also check the receiver's class).

So whenever there is an explicit receiver (even if it's `self` inside an instance method definition), that call is a "public call".

Comment: how about the protected call?

Comment: A protected call is literally just a private call with an additional check of the receiver's class before returning. In terms of access control, the logic only cares about public vs. not public.